# How do I move one element to the location of another using Neon-Animations?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm currently learning Polymer for a project and I'm trying to figure out how to slide an element when clicked, in this case an image, from its default location to the location of another element. I'm able to get it to translate 'x' pixels when using the transform-animation, but I don't know how to get it to move to certain coordinates, much less the coordinates of a predefined element. This is what I have for the transform-animation now:

```
                animationConfig: {
                value: function() {
                    return {
                        name: 'transform-animation',
                        transformTo: 'translateX(-10px) translateY(-10px)',
                        node: this
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You cannot permanently move using `neon-animation`. The animation will animate the object and then restore to its normal state.

Comment: Wow okay that's a bit frustrating. Thank you.